# Preprocess string for efficient search

Tags: python

I have a fixed string `S` of size `n` on which I make a lot of substring queries. One way to optimise for this situation is to preprocess the string and build a suffix tree, or suffix array. After preprocessing, substring queries can be performed optimally on `S`.

Is there an easy way, in Python, to preprocess strings "out of the box", without having to manually write all the code to build a suffix tree or suffix array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the [emsre](http://code.google.com/p/esmre/) python package provides exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm playing around at interviewstreet.com

Comment: It would be nice to see an answer that does it without an assist from a (likely complex) library. Basically - is there a solution that we can grok in O(1) time