# Is there a Python equivalent for Perl's `study`?

Tags: python, regex, perl, optimization

From Perl's [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/study.html):

> `study` takes extra time to study SCALAR ($_ if unspecified) in anticipation of doing 
>   many pattern matches on the string before it is next modified. This may or may not save
>   time, depending on the nature and number of patterns you are searching and the distribution
>   of character frequencies in the string to be searched;

I'm trying to speed up some regular expression-driven parsing that I'm doing in Python, and I remembered this trick from Perl. I realize I'll have to benchmark to determine if there is a speedup, but I can't find an equivalent method in Python.

Comment: Python allows to compile a regular expression object with `re.compile(...)`, but that covers the regexp side. I haven't heard of anything in Python that would study the string that is to be searched.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [Preprocess string for efficient search](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9370740/1183387). Oops!

Comment: Are you asking if python has a feature that actual slows down your matches and doesn't handle much beyond ASCII? (I think they're making `study` a no-op in 5.16.)

Comment: @Frg, `re.compile` would be the equivalent of Perl's `qr//`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there's nothing like this built into Python. But according to [the perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/study.html):

> The way study works is this: a linked list of every character in the
>   string to be searched is made, so we know, for example, where all the
>   'k' characters are. From each search string, the rarest character is
>   selected, based on some static frequency tables constructed from some
>   C programs and English text. Only those places that contain this
>   "rarest" character are examined.

This doesn't sound very sophisticated, and you could probably hack together something equivalent yourself.

[esmre](http://code.google.com/p/esmre) is kind of vaguely similar. And [as @Frg noted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9574196#comment-12139523), you'll want to use `re.compile` if you're reusing a single regex (to avoid re-parsing the regex itself over and over).

Or you could use [suffix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) (here's [one implementation](https://github.com/kvh/Python-Suffix-Tree), or here's a [C extension with unicode support](http://researchonsearch.blogspot.com/2010/05/suffix-tree-implementation-with-unicode.html)) or [suffix arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) ([implementation](http://code.google.com/p/pysuffix/)).

Comment: Thanks for the interesting reading. Your link should be [esmre](https://code.google.com/p/esmre/), though, not emsre. I'm pretty sure at this point that I don't need the `study` capability, but your answer was very helpful. I was already compiling my regular expressions.

Answer (score 8):

Perl’s study doesn’t really do much anymore.  The regex compiled has gotten a whole, whole lot smarter than it was when `study` was created.

For example, it compiles alternatives into a trie structure with Aho–Corasick prediction.

Run with `perl -Mre=debug` to see the sorts of cleverness the regex compiler and execution engine apply.